# Retrieve posts from current User's friends

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery, pfuser

The principle is that user can post opinions and only his friends can see them

So I will show you the data model and explanations to understand well

**'User' table:**

*objectId, username, email etc... (all of default fields provided by Parse and many others but not necessary to quote for my question)*

*friends; Array - it contains all the users (objectid) that are friends with him -*

*updatedAt; (provided by default)*

*createdAt; (provided by default)*

**'Opinion' table:**

*objectId;*

*senderId; Pointer User table*

*content; String*

*updatedAt; (provided by default)*

*createdAt; (provided by default)*

So I though about some tricks, querying all users before and do a restriction with  with `"wherekey:@"objectId" containedIn:"[[PFuser currentUser] objectForKey:@"friends]"` following by a query on the Opinion table restricting Opinions posts only to current User's friends... but without results...

Does anyone knows an easier way the to do this ?

Comment: You can use PFRelation in case if you expect lots of friends. Arrays are supposed to be used for a few objects, otherwise it looks good.

Comment: In my opinion, also, from what I already have implemented, it is best to implement a friends table.